# Is any finite power of a symmetric subset again symmetric?

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, topological-groups

> **Definition**
>
> A topological group is a group $(X,\,*,\,\cal T)$ equipped with a topology $\cal T$ with respect to which the functions
> $$
> p:X\times X\ni (x_1,x_2)\longrightarrow x_1*x_2\in X\quad\text{and}\quad s:X\ni x\longrightarrow x^{-1}\in X
> $$
> are continuous.

So we say that a neighborhood $V_0$ of $x_0\in X$ is symmetric if the identity holds
$$
V_0=V^{-1}_0
$$
where we put
$$
V^{-1}_0:=\{x\in X:x=y^{-1}\,\text{with }y\in V_0\}
$$

So we observe that if $x\in V_0^n$ for any $n\in\Bbb N^+$ then there exists $\xi_1(x),\dots,\xi_n(x)\in V_0$ such that
$$
x=\xi_1(x)*\dots*\xi_n(x)
$$
so that if $x\in(V_0^n)^{-1}$ and so $x^{-1}\in V_0^n$ then there exists $\xi_1(x^{-1}),\dots,\xi_n(x^{-1})\in V_0$ such that
$$
x=\big(\xi_n(x^{-1})\big)^{-1}*\dots*\big(\xi_1(x^{-1})\big)^{-1}
$$
but $V_0$ is symmetric and thus $\xi\big(\xi_n(x^{-1})\big)^{-1},\dots,\big(\xi_1(x^{-1})\big)^{-1}\in V_0$ which proves that $x\in V_0^n$: so we conclude that
$$
(V_0^n)^{-1}\subseteq V_0^n
$$
Finally, we observe that
$$
x^{-1}=\big(\xi_1(x)*\dots*\xi_n(x)\big)^{-1}=\big(\xi_n(x))^{-1}*\dots*\big(\xi_1(x))^{-1}
$$
for any $x\in V_0^n$ but again $V_0$ is symmetric and so $\big(\xi_1(x)\big)^{-1},\dots,\big(\xi_n(x)\big)^{-1}\in V_0$ so that $x^{-1}\in V_0^n$ and thus
$$
x=(x^{-1})^{-1}\in(V_0^n)^{-1}
$$
which proves that
$$
V_0^n\subseteq(V_0^n)^{-1}
$$

So I ask if the result effectively holds and thus I ask if I well proved it or if it is possibile to prove it with more simple argumentations. So coulds someone help me, please?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: @MarcinKotowski Okay, thanks for your check: indeed, none text enunciate this result so that I was not sure about its correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with topology, let alone neighborhoods (I corrected the title of this post.) You simply proved that if a subset $V$ of a group satisfies $V=V^{-1}$, then $V^n=(V^n)^{-1}$.

(Notice in passing that $V\subset V^{-1}$ and $V^{-1}\subset V$ are equivalent, hence both equivalent to $V=V^{-1}$.)

Your proof can be written more succintly: since (for any subset $V$) $(V^n)^{-1}=(V^{-1})^n$,
$$V=V^{-1}\Rightarrow V^n=(V^{-1})^n=(V^n)^{-1}.$$

Comment: Okay, all clear: question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance. See you soon. ;-)